# CreateBuilder Doctrine2

Tags: symfony2, doctrine2

¿Conoceis algún metodo de CreateBuilder(Doctrine), para que lea un array ?
Me explico:

```
class ExamplesRepository extends EntityRepository {

public function FindArticulosPadresid($padre) {

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('seccion')
                    ->select('seccion.literal','seccion.id')
                    ->where('seccion.id IN(:tpadre)')
                    ->setParameter('tpadre', **array($tpadre))** 
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
}
```

}

le estoy pasando un array **$tpadre**, que es muy simple contiene numeros enteros:

```
    array(11) 
        { [0]=> int(4)
          [1]=> int(22)
          [2]=> int(2)
          [3]=> int(2)
          [4]=> int(1)
          [5]=> int(3)
          [6]=> int(4)
          [7]=> int(3)
          [8]=> int(2)
          [9]=> int(1)
          [10]=> int(3) }
```

El problema esque solo me devuelve el primero indice (0),resultado de la **QUERY**¿Hay algún método de Doctrine que lea todo el array y devuelva todos los resultados posibles?

Gracias.

Comment: probaste pasarlo sin índices? (array(4,3,4,5))

Comment: @h40s4m4 En php, un array siempre tiene índices.

Answer (score 0):

Estás pasando el array tpadre dentro de un array, en realidad estás pasando esto:

```
array(1) {
 [0] => array(11) 
    { [0]=> int(4)
      [1]=> int(22)
      [2]=> int(2)
      [3]=> int(2)
      [4]=> int(1)
      [5]=> int(3)
      [6]=> int(4)
      [7]=> int(3)
      [8]=> int(2)
      [9]=> int(1)
      [10]=> int(3) 
    }
}
```

Prueba con así:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('seccion')
                ->select('seccion.literal','seccion.id')
                ->where('seccion.id IN(:tpadre)')
                ->setParameter('tpadre', $tpadre) 
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```